# Find the value of P Markov matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't know how to type the formula here, please look at the picture.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you tried ? And where are you stuck ?

Comment: I think you will get a much better response if you try to learn how to write your question with mathjax. See this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some starting points. 

Writing in mathjax means other users can avoid clicking on potentially precarious links and when the image is taken down from its hosting site the question still makes sense.